# Insert into many to many field Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to build Reddit in Django and for that, I am creating a board where users can discuss topics. But I am not able to map user and board.

Model:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User_Detail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="board_creator")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=
True)


class UserBoardMapping(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User_Detail)
    board = models.ManyToManyField(Board)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE, default='moderator')
```

My view:

```
class CreateBoard(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
      data = JSONParser().parse(request)
      unique_id = data.get('board_id', None)
      created_by = data.get('created_by', None)
      name = data.get('name', None)

    if not created_by or not name:
        return Response({'ERROR': 'Please provide both username and password'},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    if Board.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
        return JsonResponse({'ERROR': "Board Already registered! "},
                            status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)

    if not User_Detail.objects.filter(username=created_by).exists():
        return JsonResponse({'ERROR': "Username is not registered! "},
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    username = User_Detail.objects.get(username=created_by)
    board = Board(unique_id=unique_id, created_by=username, name=name)
    board.save()

    user_board_mapping = UserBoardMapping(user=username, board=board)
    user_board_mapping.save()
```

error:

```
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead.
```

UserBoardMapping is not working, how can I map user and board and Insert data in many to many field what am I doing wrong here in this code?

Comment: Please extend you error description beyond "is not working".

Comment: I have added the error

Answer (score 0):

For your UserBoardMapping, `user` and `board` are M2M fields. Because of that, you have to use `.set()`like in your error message. You can also use `.add()`if you want to add a value, like in your example.

```
user_board_mapping = UserBoardMapping.objects.create(user_type='whatyouwant')
user_board_mapping.user.add(username)
user_board_mapping.board.add(board)
```

You can find here some examples : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships